# Duda sobre tipos genéricos y wildcars en Java

Tags: java, genericos

Os cuento, a ver si puedo sacar más cosas en claro. Tengo la siguiente clase creada con genéricos en Java y tengo varias dudas acerca de esto:

```
    public class Averias<T, E> {

    private ArrayList<T> averias;
    private E prueba;
    private ArrayList<? extends T> animal;

    public Averias(ArrayList<T> averias, E prueba, ArrayList<? extends T> animal) {
        this.averias = averias;
        this.prueba = prueba;
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getAverias() {
        return averias;
    }

    public void setAverias(ArrayList<T> averias) {
        this.averias = averias;
    }

    public E getPrueba() {
        return prueba;
    }

    public void setPrueba(E prueba) {
        this.prueba = prueba;
    }

    public ArrayList<? extends T> getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(ArrayList<? extends T> animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase, y ahora la primera duda que tengo es: cuando quiera usar esta clase, ¿tengo que inferir todos los tipos o puedo usar solo alguno?

```
private Averias<Integer, String> averias;
```

Si infiero todos los tipos funciona, pero me parece mucho código que cada vez que quiera usarlo, tenga que inferir el tipo, entonces no se si existe alguna forma más sencilla que no sepa.

En la clase tengo un ArrayList con un wildcard: `private ArrayList<? extends T> animal;`. Todavía no tengo muy claro como funcionan los wildcards, se que se puede poner solo, con extends o con super, y dependiendo funciona de una forma u otra, pero no me queda claro cuando me sería útil usarlos.

Comment: ¿Aún requieres una respuesta a esta pregunta?

Comment: Toda respuesta que pueda servirme para ampliar mis conocimientos es bienvenida, así que adelante.